Can you somehow use underscore to ignore different results in Unity like you would do with TryParse?
So I may not be the best programmer, but I am not a beginner. So in C# when you want to check if... lets say if its a number or not, but you dont care about the result(the  you could write something like this:
  private static void NumberCheck(string prompt)
    {
        bool isNumber = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);

           isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out _);
        } while (!isNumber);

        Console.WriteLine("Wrote ");
    }

So a pretty bad method, but you get it. You dont care about the number. So I was using "Collider.Cast();" in Unity, basically checking for collisions and you have to provide it with where to check and then put the result in a RaycastHit2D variable. But I dont want to do anything with the RaycastHit2D result, I only want the int the method returns. So here is the code:
 IsGrounded = _touchingColl.Cast(Vector2.down, _groundHits, _groundDistance) > 0;

(bool) ^-------(Collider) ^--(Direction to cast)^ (store result ^in RaycastHit variable)
So I dont care about _groundhits which is just an array of RaycastHit2D, I dont want to do anything with it. I dont care about it, I only want the int that the method gives me. So can I somehow ignore it? But I dont seem to be able to underscore like the number check example?

Isnt your _ just the name of the variable? You read from the console, store the result in _ and check afterwards if _ is a number or not. But you could have named it input, stringToParse, test12345 or totallyAwesomeName. The _ just seems like a lazy short name. But you probably stumble that you didn't declare _ as you did with _groundHits, read more what out does here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169786/when-should-i-use-out-parameters?rq=3

It is the name of the variable, but a couple of videos and books that I read/watched said that if you dont want to use the result than just write underscore. I dont use the "_" variable to check if its a number or not. TryParse returns a bool that tells you if its true or false. and I only wanted to loop while its false. I never needed the result value in that code? My question is basically if I need to declare a variable at the top and use that variable. I would like to just declare the variable in that "Collider.Cast" method without having to declare it, because I dont use it.

@Zibelas A single underscore is a special keyword in C#. It means "discard the result": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards

@MrV A discard is just an underscore by itself, not an underscore in front of an identifier. _groundHits is not a discard.

What shape is this collider? If you just want to know "is there at least one thing in the ground layer overlapping this shape" you can probably get that from one of the Physics2D static isTouching / overlap / shapecast methods, without requesting an array of results you don't plan to use.

@Kevin thx, something new to learn is always nice

@DMGregory I am using a CapsuleCollider2D. As you say Physics2D also offers methods to check for different kinds of collisions. To be honest, I am kinda overwhelmed by all different methods, like how am I supposed to know which methods I should use? Like in this case, should I use the Cast method that exists on the collider, or should I go with a method in the physics class? Its just to much I dont know. I want to make an inventory, A save/load system or planets that are alive(sand storms, animals etc...) or just cool visuals. But I dont know where to look for help.

You're on the right page, you just need to focus on the problem you're trying to solve ("How do I write an efficient 2D ground check with a capsule collider?") not on your guess at a solution ("can I somehow discard the results array?") — this is a common trap called the X/Y Problem. Try posting a new question about that root problem, and we can help you write a check that does not require allocating an array. Then you can post another question about the next step, like the inventory or save/load system.

In short, no. That is called a discard, and those can only be used in a few specific scenarios. See the link for a complete list, but the summary is at the beginning of the page:

You may want to ignore the result of an expression, one or more members of a tuple expression, an out parameter to a method, or the target of a pattern matching expression.

Since the results parameter is does not use the out keyword, you cannot discard it.
The closest thing would probably be something like:
_touchingColl.Cast(Vector2.down, new RaycastHit2D[n], _groundDistance)

But, of course, that will allocate a new array every time you run that code, which is rather wasteful.

If you don't care about the results, the correct way to handle this without allocating a new array every time is to use a static array.

@Pikalek Did you mean to post that comment on this answer? This answer does not suggest that using an underscore as a prefix is still a discard (though there are two underscores used as prefixes in the line of code, those are taken directly from the question).

@Kevin I did, but in retrospect it's redundant with my answer. I still think this answer muddies things a bit as it starts with the discard version of _ but then uses the non discard prefix version with _groundDistance and doesn't specifically call out that those are two different uses.

So from what I understand from all this. You cant "discard" something if its not with a out keyword. Either you go with it or you try to find another method solution for it.

Using the underscore as a prefix, for example _VarName, is not a discard, it is a naming convention. It's something people do for organization purposes, but it doesn't impact the meaning of the code with respect to the compiler / language. As explained here in the C# docs on naming conventions:

In addition to the rules, conventions for identifier names are used
throughout the .NET APIs. These conventions provide consistency for
names, but the compiler doesn't enforce them. You're free to use
different conventions in your projects.
...

Private instance fields start with an underscore (_) and the remaining text is camelCased....


As mentioned in this SO question & answer, it could be used to indicate a parameter was not to be used in the function. I'd advise against using it in this way because that's not the expected use.
